# Getting duplicate result while joining tables

Tags: php, mysql

When im using Select statement for displaying data from Mysql Db. Im getting Duplicate Values. How to Solve this issue? My sql Query is this:

```
$sql="SELECT r.hosteladmissionno,r.student_name,r.semester,
         m.billmonth,m.billyear,m.wastagecharge,b.exp_amount
  FROM  registration r, messexp m, blockexp b
  WHERE r.mess_type = '".$q."' AND r.mess_type=m.messtype AND r.status_flag=1";
```

Comment: Please format the SQL so that we don't have to scroll

Comment: use `DISTINCT` AFTER `select`

Comment: DISTINCT provides a row distinct on all columns. Are you sure you have an exact duplicate row with same value in all the selected columns?

Comment: `status_flag` belongs to which table??

Comment: I think one of the edits has removed the DISTINCT keyword that was there in the initial post.

Comment: i have just formatted the query

Comment: Yeah krishna.. I removed it... COs i tested with Distinct and pasted it here. @echo.. it belongs to registration table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use inner join in you query. Else each result of registration will be combined with each result of messexp ...

```
$sql="SELECT registration.hosteladmissionno,
    registration.student_name,
    registration.semester,
    messexp.billmonth,
    messexp.billyear,
    messexp.wastagecharge,
    blockexp.exp_amount
FROM registration
INNER JOIN messexp ON (messexp.id_registration = registration.id)
INNER JOIN blockexp ON (blockexp.id_messexp = messexp.id)
 WHERE 
registration.mess_type = '".$q."' AND status_flag=1";
```

Please note that ON (...) will change depending on you schema

Comment: Thanks i will try it ..freye.. Where is id_registration coming from?

Comment: @Dinzy it was a supposition of your schema. In general, to make an association between two tables, you are using an id that come from one of two table. eg. Tables => Student(id, lastname, firstname, id_class...)  and Class(id, name, description, etc..). You have an association between a Studant and a Class. It mean that the student is in Class referenced by id_class

Answer (score 3):

You have cross-joined the tables, so you get every combination of results.
Connect the tables in the where clause:

```
select tab1.column1, table2.column1
from tab1, tab2
where tab1.fkColumn = tab2.idColumn
```

What are the columns that connect the tables to each other?

Comment: You also have to connect the table blockexp. Otherwise you would cross join it like before.